# How to convert a video file to XVID format?

Tags: windows, video, conversion, xvid

I need to convert existing MP4 files to the XVID format with the .AVI extension.  Specifically to something like this:

[image]

I've tried Camtasia, Handbrake and VLC, but they don't seem to support this format - I guess its really old.  Everything else I've googled seems like something that will install a ton of spyware on my PC.

Comment: Have you tried entering `convert mp4 xvid` into google?

Comment: @LPChip Of course... it says so in my question.

Comment: There are several free applications available in google for this application. Also same is discussed here in this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/122147/need-to-convert-a-video-file-from-mp4-to-xvid

Comment: Have you gone to http://www.xvid.org/ and downloaded their free codec? Why on earth you would want to transcode to AVI using an XVid container from an MP4 which is likely using h264 codec where as XVid using h263. AVI are a total PITA to use re: video editing in that they are very often not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freemake](http://www.freemake.com/) will do this as below. It's the single best converter out there as far as I'm concerned. Open source and malware free. Does a superb job re: compression and supports tons of formats.

As per my comment tho dunno why you'd to go to AVI container with Xvid codec from MP4.

[image]

Comment: I used this application.  During the setup you have to uncheck all bunch of stuff to avoid installing all manner of toolbars, etc... but after the installation it worked perfectly.

Comment: @AngryHacker Yes you're right. I've just installed on another Win 8 image and it does have those, somewhat sneaky,  opt out of optional installs, a bit like uTorrent. There are two of them that need to be radio checked to say no thanks. But that aside the program itself is not malware or up to anything improper. Been along while still i installed so forgot about that.

Comment: As for now (December 2018) this program will add a mark to the video or will be slower when converting if you don't buy a payment version.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I could think of is file type checker http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html could be help full.

A demuxer could be best option because wont loose quality re compressing, it will just split the video up into it's audio n video.

Digital Digest is a great site, very helpful for this sort of thing, I have been using it for many a years!

AV Splitter 1.2 may work for you, its on there site.

parts.http://www.digital-digest.com/software/category-14.html

Good Luck!

Comment: trid is awesome. Your second link though, looks dodgy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried VirtualDub?  As long as you have the codecs installed, or download the addins, VDUB can usually perform the conversion.

http://www.virtualdub.org/index.html

From Vdub (http://forums.virtualdub.org/index.php?s=43b1e5503ee6baa8b85866ddf58b64b6&act=ST&f=7&t=14639&st=105)

> And here's the first release for quicktime video (mov, some mp4,
>   etc.):
>
> binary http://www.tateu.net/software/dl.php?f=qtvd_bin
>
> source code http://www.tateu.net/software/dl.php?f=qtvd_src
>
> "Quicktime.vdplugin" should go in your plugins32 folder and
>   "Quicktime.ini" should go in the VirtualDub root folder.
>
> There are several different modes that can be used to open a movie,
>   these are specified in Quicktime.ini as "mode=." Mode=-1 and color=-1
>   are the recommended defaults but you can read about the different
>   modes in "Quicktime_ReadMe.txt." Eventually, these options will be
>   implemented as an "Ask for Extended Options Dialog."
>
> Audio is currently not implemented and I am sure there are many bugs.
>   Questions, comments, suggestions, whatever...are welcome.
>
> I will also most likely...someday...implement my avisynth OMF
>   importer.

And how to perform the conversion guides are here:

(http://www.videohelp.com/guides/how-to-convert-to-divx-avi-with-virtualdub-id91)

Comment: Would be good if you could be more specific as to how to install the codecs (which ones?), addins (which ones?), and then perform the actual conversion.

Comment: I added a little more detail, most of this information was already created by others.